# USB Boot Client for PXE

Tags: boot, system-installation

Trying to find an image of a bootable USB stick with a **client** for Netboot, once the PC which would to receive the installation doesn't have `PXE` access in its BIOS, while the `tftpd-hpa` server is already running with an `Ubuntu 18.04` image and proper `pxelinux.0` file.

Any idea on where could be found such bootable image?

Comment: It's an image of a CLIENT for Netboot that is seeked, not a server. Have a `tftpd-hpa` server enabled here and an old PC without Netboot option in BIOS, and would like to boot an installation image in it via Netboot with an USB stick.

Comment: Just adjusted it, may verify please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can a USB or CD , please look at :

https://wiki.syslinux.org/wiki/index.php?title=PXELINUX

or

http://ipxe.org/